# How to exclude trailing slash in a single route in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, trailing-slash

I have a problem with Next.js Trailing Slash on some pages, I am using media query like:

`/test?type=something`

but with a trailing slash, I am getting

`/test/?type=something`

Is there any solution to remove the trailing slash on some specific pages?

Answer (score 0):

currently, You can only set the behavior for **all pages**.

according to the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash):

Open `next.config.js` and config the `trailingSlash`:

```js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true/false,
}
```